# CAKEPHP Reset cookieTimeout on activity

Tags: session, cakephp, timeout, session-cookies, session-timeout

I have problem to make my application is not logged out user on activity

[image: this is my core.php]

I have code like the picture above

as we know, modify the cakephp session is able by that code

"timeout" values is used to set how long session will be expired in a minutes. and the "autoRegenerate" value is used to renew the timeout value

and the last is "cookieTimeout" is used to set how long activity allowed

the crux of my question is how to auto regenerated the cookieTimeout cakephp in core.php (like renew "timeout" value with "autoRegenerate" => true)

Thanks in advance